# How to add the date in JMeter from date picker?

Tags: date, datepicker, jmeter

Date picker used in our application has 2 dropdowns in it (list of months and years) in UI. Manual input is disabled for some reason and hence it's getting difficult for us to handle it in jmeter.

[image]

Scenario is:

User will select **Year first > then month > then date** in **FROM** dropdown and **TO** dropdown will contain any date (select Year first>then month> then date) which is greater than date selected in **FROM** but wil be less or equal to today's date.

How can I achieve the same on jmeter? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the date value is being send to the server in one parameter, or in three, for example

```
date = "12/01/2019"  
day = 01
month = 12
year = 2019
```

You need to [record your scenario](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording/) of choosing and submiting a date by using the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and to see how it sends in the request.

Comment: no, as said in above query, date field is disabled for some reason. above already is of no use as I have to make sure that TO date it greater than FROM

Comment: So, do you get the first date (FROM) from the server, and do you want to calculate the second date (TO)?
Or you set all dates by yourself?

Comment: its all set by myself

Comment: I suppose, there are two ways how is the `date TO value` calculates:
1. By the server. In this case you need to record first request with FROM date value and get the list of generated TO dates in it's responce. Send parsed date in the next request.
2. By the client, with javascript. In this case just send the dates what you need in recorded requests.

Was it helpful? If there are still questions, could you share your requests?